# c# add integer to list

Tags: c#, .net

When I check if a textbox equals 1, I want to check if the list allready contains a specific value. When I run this, it allways goes to the else code. What am I doing wrong?

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();

if (Convert.ToInt32(DobbelWaarde.Text) == 1)
{
    if (list.Contains(1))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("1 is allready been chosen");
    }
    else
    {
        list.Add(1);
        Console.WriteLine();
        foreach (int li in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(li);
            Console.WriteLine("We add 1");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: because your list is always empty since you create it like that right before the first if

Comment: Are you creating a new list everytime?

Comment: If that isn't in a for or you have some missing code it is normal.

Answer (score 12):

The first line [initialises](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) an empty list:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
```

The list is empty so [Contains()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx) returns false, no matter what the value you check for is.

To initialise the list you could use:

```
List<int> list = new List<int> { 1 };
```

More details are here:
[Object and Collection Initializers (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx)

Comment: probably you may suggest to declare the List in a scope that remembers its state. Like either make it a data-member or static variable

Answer (score 4):

> When I run this, it allways goes to the else code.

You are not adding integer in your list anywhere. You start with **an empty List** and then check if it contains `1` that is why it goes to the else part.

You may initialize the list like:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>() {1};
```

Comment: I believe initializing with 1 is not a solution. Because in that case, the code will always run into inner if block, which I believe @Optical would not want that to happen.

Comment: @Romaan, its actually not clear what the OP exactly need ?, I wanted him to understand that the list needs to contain some element and atleast element with value `1`, so that the if part of the check executes

Comment: Okay :) Marked positive @Habib

Answer (score 2):

I don't get ur code !

First ur list have no element

Your code , it may be like this:

```
 List<int> list = new List<int>();
    list.Add(1);
    list.Add(2);
    list.Add(3);
    list.Add(4);

 int number = Convert.ToInt32(DobbelWaarde.Text);

        if ( number == 1)
        {
            if (list.Contains(1))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(number + " is allready been chosen");
            }
            else
            {
                list.Add(number );
                Console.WriteLine();
                foreach (int li in list)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(li);
                    Console.WriteLine("We add " + number);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You initialize the list always before you check if it contains that number. That will clear the list.
So you should move the initialization for example into the constructor of your class:

```
class MyClass
{
    List<int> list;
    public MyClass()
    {
        list  = new List<int>();
    }

    private void Validate()
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(DobbelWaarde.Text) == 1)
        {
            if (list.Contains(1))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("1 is allready been chosen");
            }
            else
            {
                list.Add(1);
                // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

condition in the if statement is always evaluated to false i.e  list doesn't have 1 so it returns false hence else part gets executed.

Answer (score 0):

Define your `list` outer checkTextBox method:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();

void CheckTextBox()
{
    if (Convert.ToInt32(DobbelWaarde.Text) == 1)
    {
        if (list.Contains(1))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("1 is allready been chosen");
        }
        else
        {
            list.Add(1);
            Console.WriteLine();
            foreach (int li in list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(li);
                Console.WriteLine("We add 1");
            }
        }
    }
}
```